# merge multiple lines into one line based on counting the number of occurrences of delimiter for each line

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I have data like this:

```
RE_1|Emp_1|cty_1|analyst_1|end
RE_2|EMP_2|cty_2|analyst_2|end
RE_3|EMP_3|cty
_3|analyst_3|end
RE_4|EMP_4|cty_4|analyst_4|end
```

The third line got split into two lines. I need to merge those split lines into one. Every line should have 4 pipe delimeters. So I need to count the number of `|` in each line. If it is 4 print the line. If not 4 then merge the next line with that and check the count. If it is still not 4, merge the next line as well. Repeat until the line contains 4 `|` delimiters.

The original file contains millions of rows out of which 10000's are split like this. So I need a solution for this either in PowerShell or Windows batch which merge the lines quickly.

Answer (score 2):

You could perhaps use a regular expression like this:

```
... -replace '(?ms)^((?:[^\|\r\n]*\|){2}[^\|\r\n]*?)\r?\n((?:[^\|\r\n]*\|){2}end)', '$1$2'
```

However, I wouldn't recommend processing files with millions of records in-memory. It's not really fun when your computer comes grinding to a halt after it started swapping due to memory exhaustion. Processing the file in a pipeline avoids this kind of issue:

```
$merged = ''
Get-Content 'C:\path\to\input.txt' | ForEach-Object {
  if ($_ -notlike '*|*|*|*|*') {
    # if the line doesn't have 4 pipe characters in it: append it to the
    # merged line variable and move on to the next line
    $merged += $_
  } else {
    # if the line does have 4 pipe characters in it: output and clear the
    # merged line variable if it contains a value, then output the current
    # line
    if ($merged) {
      $merged
      $merged = ''
    }
    $_
  }
} | Set-Content 'C:\path\to\output.txt'

# if the input file didn't end with a non-wrapped line the trailing wrapped lines
# haven't been written to the output file yet
if ($merged) {
  $merged | Add-Content 'C:\path\to\output.txt'
}
```

Comment: Note I do respect your knowledge but why do you answer questions like this that should be closed?

Comment: @Matt Because I felt generous yesterday, and I think the question and answer might be useful to other people as well, despite the OP's lack of effort. Besides, nobody even voted to close the question yet.